# (RAD Studio) Virtual TreeView: how to initialize all nodes at once?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I just discovered this component and started working with it.

I understand that the whole concept of it is to initialize nodes on the go as they are needed but I need all of them to initialize instantly.

What is the smart way to do it?

The only thing I came up with is to use *GetLast()* after adding nodes.
I believe, there is a better way, or not?

Comment: Can you explain "why" you need all nodes be initialized instantly? In this case the Virtual TreeView looses much of its speed and "virtuality".

Comment: Because it is a bad design and I do not have an option to change software design and make it virtual :(

Comment: The "smart way" is to **not do that**.

Comment: Well, if you are working with databases the virtual paradigm must be violated. Otherwise you get unexpected results when accessing nodes "on demand".

Comment: @Wodzu: does it mean that I should go for another component or simply compromise "virtuality"?

Comment: @Andrew, No apart from that what I've mentioned VritualTree is great. I am using it in my commercial projects in conjunction with databases and it works without any problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

treeview.FullExpand;

Answer (score 7):

The more correct way to initialize a single node instantly, is to use the ValidateNode method, instead of already suggested FullExpand. According to the VT's documantation:

```
procedure ValidateNode(Node: PVirtualNode; Recursive: Boolean);
```

> **TBaseVirtualTree.ValidateNode Method**
>
> ValidateNode ensures that the given
>   node (and all its children, if
>   Recursive is true) are initialized. If
>   Node is nil then the hidden root node
>   is used (which makes only sense if
>   Recursive is true, in which case the
>   entire tree is validated).

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer, since FullExpand will change **visually** expand the entire tree which you might don't want it to happen.

Answer (score 4):

You can write your own procedure to build treeview manually.

Example:

```
procedure TForm1.BuildTree;
var
  i: integer;
  Data: ^TYourRecord;
  pNode, cNode: PVirtualNode;
begin
  for i:=0 to 1000 - 1 do
  begin
    //build parent node
    pNode := VT.AddChild(nil);
    Data := VT.GetNodeData(pNode);
    //fill record values
    Data.SomeVar := 'Parent Node';
    //build child node
    cNode := VT.AddChild(pNode);
    Data := VT.GetNodeData(cNode);
    Data.SomeVar := 'Child Node';
  end;
end;
```